# Conditional Formatting lost when range from several worksheets copied to Outlook email with Range to HTML

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook

I have an Excel workbook that has 8 worksheets. I have details about a marketing promotion on each sheet in range(A2:Q9).

I have VBA code that copies this range from each worksheet, converts it using the `RangetoHTML` function from Ron de Bruin's [site](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm), and then pastes it into an Outlook email with recipients listed in several variables.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub SendEmails()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

   Dim outlookApp As Object
   Dim outlookMail As Object
   
   'Recipients
   Dim recipientGroup1 As String
      
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim cf As Range
   Dim cft As Range
   Dim rng As Range
   Dim tempChart As ChartObject
   Dim tempChartPath As String
   Dim emailBody As String
   Dim S As String
   Dim alert As VbMsgBoxResult

   ' Define recipient group email addresses
   recipientGroup1 = "email@email.com;"

   ' Create Outlook application object
   Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

' Group 1 - Test
   Set outlookMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)
   emailBody = "<b>Greetings,</b><p><b>This is an auto-generated email.</b><p><b>Promotions have been updated. Please review thoroughly:</b><p>"
   S = Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\"
   If Dir(S, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then S = S & Dir$(S & "*.htm") Else S = ""
   S = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(S).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2).ReadAll

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("STD", "STD", "AHS", "48HRS", "INTL LAND", "INTL", "Mobile", "OPQ")) ' Add more sheets as needed
    Set cf = ws.Range("R2:R8")
    Set cft = ws.Range("Q2:Q7")
    cf.Copy
    cft.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Set rng = ws.Range("A2:Q9")
    emailBody = emailBody
    emailBody = emailBody & RangetoHTML(rng)
    emailBody = emailBody
Next ws

With outlookMail
   .To = recipientGroup1
   .CC = recipientGroup1
   .Subject = "*UPDATED* Promotions"
   .HTMLBody = emailBody & "<p><b>If you have any additional inquiries or concerns, reply all to the team.</b><p>" & S
   .Display
End With

   Set outlookApp = Nothing
   Set outlookMail = Nothing
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Occasionally, I make changes to the details of the promotion. Each promotion is copied and then pasted into range(A12:Q19) on a separate Sub/Macro not listed above. I created some formulas in cells(R2:R9) that provide TRUE/FALSE indicators if the copied promotion is different from original/updated range in (A2:Q9) line-by-line. If the cell is TRUE, certain cells will be conditionally formatted red to indicated change.
[image]

For example, if R8 indicates TRUE, this means that the values in B8 are different against B18. Since this is true, I apply conditional formatting for B8 to turn red.

**THE ISSUE** is that when the macro runs, conditional formatting is lost when the range(s) are pasted into an Outlook email.

Comment: Is applying the formatting directly to the cells with VBA an option?

Comment: The formatting is lost even when applying conditional formatting directly to the cells.

Comment: Does the answer here solve your issue? https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/rangetohtml-and-conditional-formatting.1037243/

Comment: I have seen this forum prior to your response. Unfortunately, it copies the same exact range from one workbook, and pastes it 8 times into my outlook item, instead of cycling through each worksheet and performing the function. Do you suggest any changes to the code in the forum?

Comment: I don't see how the code from the forum post would paste something 8 times. Are you using a loop or running the code mutliple times?

Comment: I added a loop into the RngtoHTML function. Sadly, I used ChatGPT to help me develop the code after I explained to it that it needs to loop through the worksheets I list in the array. I have answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the updated RngtoHTML function I used to loop through the array, and copy/paste the range I defined earlier in the code.

```
Function RangetoHTML(ws As Worksheet, rng As Range) As String
    ' Code to convert range to HTML
    ' Adapted from Ron de Bruin - https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm
    ' Working in Excel 2000-2016

    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim ddo As Long

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    ' Temporary publish the rng range to an HTML file
    ddo = ws.Parent.DisplayDrawingObjects
    ws.Parent.DisplayDrawingObjects = xlHide
    With ws.Parent.PublishObjects.Add( _
        SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
        Filename:=TempFile, _
        Sheet:=ws.Name, _
        Source:=rng.Address, _
        HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish True
        .Delete
    End With
    ws.Parent.DisplayDrawingObjects = ddo

    ' Read all data from the HTML file into RangetoHTML
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
        RangetoHTML = .ReadAll
        .Close
    End With

    ' Delete the HTML file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

End Function
```

Comment: Only downfall is that it pastes the ranges I defined into my Outlook item with centered alignment. Regardless, it keeps the conditional formatting I want from the original workbook.

Comment: If you look at the code from the forum post, they use `RangetoHTML = Replace(.ReadAll, "align=center x:publishsource=", "align=left x:publishsource=")` instead of `RangetoHTML = .ReadAll` which might explain why you get center alignment.

Comment: I am definitely not a coder, so I am learning a lot from all the input in this post. Thank you so much. I appreciate it!